# Simplify $(n+1)^{1/\sqrt{n}}$ and $(n^2+1)^{1/n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Which simplifications can be made to simplify $(n+1)^{1/\sqrt{n}}$ and $(n^2+1)^{1/n}$ to show formally that both expressions converge towards 1 as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: I don't know how to simplify these, but I would recommend squeeze theorem and $\sqrt[n]{n}\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Yeah I was considering $\sqrt[n]{n}\to 1$ as well but couldn't really compare the sequences to this root.

Comment: both of them are identical so if one is shown the second is too

Comment: The two expressions are identical with $n\leftrightarrow n^2$.

Comment: Take log and apply limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the annoying $+1$, you can consider that you function is sandwiched between
$$n^{1/\sqrt{n}} < (n+1)^{1/\sqrt{n}} <  (2n)^{1/\sqrt{n}} $$
for $n>1$ and these two bounds should be easier to manage (indeed both have limit $1$).

The other one is similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use approximations ie $n+1\approx n$ at large value so the series converges to $1$ same way 2nd series can be approximated.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to explain why exactly we can apply this approximation.

Comment: The $+1$ becomes negligible like  $52!+1$ that $+1$ isnt needed as $52!$ is such a gigantic number that 1 hardly matters

Comment: By the same argument you should show that the limit of $n+1-n$ is zero, because, since $n+1\approx n$. We could multiply examples of why we can't always use this, so you have to argue why we _can_ use this approimation here.

Comment: I dont have any rigorous proof why i used it here i thought that would be a good approximation here to show convergence

Comment: If you have please share with me

Answer (score 0):

You could tackle it by taking the log and then the limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n+1)}{\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\sqrt{n}}{(n+1)}\tag{L'Hospital's rule}$$

$$=0$$

$$=\log(1)$$

So the limit for the first one is $1$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n^2+1)}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n}{n^2+1}$$

$$=0$$

$$=\log(1)$$

So both limits are $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function, defined for $t>0$,
$$
f(t)=\log\left(\left(\frac{1}{t^2}+1\right)^t\right)
=t\log(1+t^2)-2t\log t
$$
Since $\lim_{t\to0^+}t\log t=0$, we clearly have $\lim_{t\to0^+}f(t)=0$.
Therefore
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\left(\frac{1}{t^2}+1\right)^t=
\lim_{t\to0^+}e^{f(t)}=1
$$
Now substitute $t=1/\sqrt{n}$.

The second is the same, with $t=1/n$.